# Pidgin is getting hanged

Tags: apt, pidgin

Yesterday, when I was trying answer a question on tor I installed it on my machine and at that point, it displayed a message saying a pidgin-XXX is not needed any more and hence run `sudo apt-get autoclean`. I mentioned it as XXX because I don't remember what that package is. I have shutdown my PC and restarted in the evening, Pidgin started to hang. Not sure of the problem, I tried installing all the pidgin plugins with `sudo apt-get install pidgin*`. This installed whole bunch of plugins. Even then it is in the same state. Can anyone let me know what I have uninstalled so I can reinstall or what need to be done to fix this issue.

I would like to update here saying that the pidgin gets hanged only when I login into my yahoo account. When I login into skype, it works fine for me. I just realized the same.

Comment: Try to run 'pidgin' from terminal and provide us the output.

Comment: I tried running pidgin from terminal using the command pidgin &> /dev/null & and it displayed the below message "Exiting because another libpurple client is already running." as it is running. When quit and run this command, it started properly as I enabled only Skype. When tried to enable yahoo, it got hung and I had to Force Quit the application

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what went wrong but I have cleaned the whole pidgin installation;

- uninstalled pidgin
- renamed all pidgin folders
- reinstalled everything
- added again yahoo account

This worked fine for me. I guess it is not the solution in Linux or Ubuntu. I hate to adopt a windows based solution but I was helpless.

Answer (score 1):

Found this tip on another thread elsewhere. I am running Pidgin from the terminal in debug mode and have not had the 'hanging' problem so far.  I have only been doing this for a few days... I start pidgin in the terminal using

```
pidgin -d
```

Comment: okay, now anyhow i do not have this problem but now i remember to use this in case i encounter this problem again. Thanks for the tip.